# Multiply a list of matrices by a list of vectors

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

How does one multiply a list of matrices by a list of vectors, elementwise? For example, multiplying

```
A = {IdentityMatrix[2], 2*IdentityMatrix[2]}
x = {{1, 1}, {2, -2}}
```

should return

```
{{1, 1}, {4, -4}}
```

Neither `Dot` nor `Times` accomplishes this; both have the wrong dimensions.  A cumbersome way would be

```
result = {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}
Do[result[[i]] = A[[i]].x[[i]], {i, 2}]
```

but surely there is a cleaner way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
MapThread[Dot, {A, x}]   // TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  1 & 1 \\
>  4 & -4 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps just:

```
Dot @@@ Transpose[{A, x}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Following Belasarius in a somewhat more transparent fashion, you Apply[ ] the Dot function to A and x. The Transpose is used to get the A and x into a single list and the "1" causes the Apply to to work at the correct level.

```
 Apply[Dot, Transpose[{A, x}], 1]
```